# Foucault's scrawny haunches

Tags: meaning

> I miss no opportunity to throw darts at **Foucault's scrawny haunches** because he is the last standing member of the Terrible Triad of French poststructuralists, whose work swept into American universities in the 1970s and drove out the home-grown radicalism of our own 1960s cultural revolution.*

Source: [What I hate about Foucault](http://www.neoliberalismo.com/Foucault.htm)

I would like to ask whether "Foucault's scrawny haunches" is used in a literal or figurative meaning. Whether the latter possibility is right than I am not able to decipher it. Can you help me?

Comment: I would assume the darts are being thrown at a likeness of Foucault. That would make the whole thing figurative.

Comment: This question is not about English but about literary criticism and writing techniques; it is not English dependent.

Comment: @Clare: The (presumably metaphorical) usage of "scrawny haunches" is a linguistic issue, regardless of the personalities involved, even if they happen to be lit-crit luminaries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has nothing to do with the English language per se; to answer it requires knowledge of Foucault's haunches: *I would like to ask whether "Foucault's scrawny haunches" is used in a literal or figurative meaning.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Scrawny haunches* is a deliberately offensive characterization of Foucault's physical appearance (he was a slender man). The haunches and the darts are both figuratively deployed, the haunches representing the "thinness" of Foucault's scholarship and intellect, and the darts representing Paglia's piercing invective.

Comment: Haunch is also the upper part of a person's leg (hip, buttock, and upper thigh), so it's probably also meant to create a "humorous" visualization of throwing darts at his rear end.

Comment: @fixer1234 I imagine there's also an echo of Samson's attack on the Philistines: "He smote them **hip and thigh**."